# connection with Facebook OK, But I lost data when i came back on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I'm going to develop an android application, and I'm trying to separate things .... I have created a FacebookConnect class to call facebook API to retrieve facebook public information to use them later but my object is null when i came back to my main Java class.

Any idea...my knowledge is average in this field of skills.

This is my function in FacebookConnect

```
public void getConnectionWithFacebook(Activity myActivity, CallbackManager mCallbackManager){
    MCALLBACKMANAGER = mCallbackManager;
    MYACTIVITY = myActivity;
    ONEUSER = new User();

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MYACTIVITY, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(MCALLBACKMANAGER, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG,"facebookSuccess3 -> " + loginResult.toString());
            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"facebookSuccess4 -> " + response.toString());
                    getDataFromFacebook(object);
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","id,email,first_name,last_name");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG,"facebook -> " + "onCancel");
            Toast.makeText(MYACTIVITY, "Une erreur s'est produite, veuillez réessayer plus tard...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"facebookONError -> " +error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MYACTIVITY, "Une erreur s'est produite, veuillez réessayer plus tard...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

In my main class , i will call this function inside of this event of click :

```
btnFBLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        FacebookConnect oneConnection = new FacebookConnect();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnFBLogin.setEnabled(false);
            oneConnection.getConnectionWithFacebook(MainActivity.this, mCallbackManager);
            String email = oneConnection.getEmail();
            Log.d(TAG,"handleFacebookToken1 -> " + email); // doesnt work
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, the result is null or empty and I don't know why.

Edit :

This is my function to associate data from facebook to my class :

```
public void getDataFromFacebook(JSONObject object) {
    try{
        String emailJSON = object.getString("email");
        String fristNameJSON = object.getString("first_name");
        String lastNameJSON = object.getString("last_name");

        Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + emailJSON);
        Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + fristNameJSON);
        Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + lastNameJSON);

        //Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + object.getString("email"));
        // Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + object.getString("first_name"));
        //Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + object.getString("last_name"));
        this.setEmail(emailJSON);
        this.setFirstName(fristNameJSON);
        this.setLastName(lastNameJSON);

        Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + getEmail());
        Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + getFirstName());
        Log.d(TAGUSER,"facebookSuccess -> " + getLastName());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I put a lot of lot every where to see what happens with de data

Thx again !

Comment: `getDataFromFacebook(object);` what do you do in this method ?

Comment: Any idea everyone ?

Comment: My issue is : 
How to retrieve the graph object and DATA facebook API from the function getConnectionWithFacebook in MainActivity around line 47
Thx
Have a nice days